# VBA Run-time error '91' - Object variable or With block variables not set - IE Button click error

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I need help with my script please. I am new to VBA and I have written the below code to load an intranet  web page and login. After login, the next step is to click on one of several buttons on the web page. I am however getting run-time error 91 from the last line of code in bold text below (IE1.document.getElementById("btnAddPerson").Click).

Could you tell me what is wrong here please?

Thanks.

Regards
Michael T

```
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal HWND As Long) As Long

Option Explicit
Private Declare Function ShowWindow _
Lib "user32" _
(ByVal HWND As Long, _
ByVal nCmdShow As Long) _
As Long

Function IEWindowFromTitle(sTitle As String) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim win As Object, rv As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    For Each win In objShellWindows
        If TypeName(win.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            If UCase(win.document.Title) = UCase(sTitle) Then
                Set rv = win
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set IEWindowFromTitle = rv

End Function
Sub Test1()

'Login into IE

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim IE1 As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim btn As HTMLButtonElement
    Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MyHTML_Element1 As IHTMLElement
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set IE1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://some_intranet_url/1" 

    Do While IE.Busy

         ShowWindow IE.HWND, 3
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)


    Loop

    Set doc = IE.document

   doc.getElementById("username").Value = "some_username"
   doc.getElementById("password").Value = "some_password"

   'Click to Login
    For Each MyHTML_Element In doc.getElementById("loginForm")
    If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next


Do While IE.Busy

         ShowWindow IE.HWND, 3
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)


    Loop
    'Selct role
    doc.getElementById("selectedRole").Value = "555885740104"

    'Click to Login
    doc.getElementById("button1").Click

        'Click to add person


  Do While IE.Busy

        ' ShowWindow IE.HWND, 3
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)


'Set page to be fully loaded
    Loop

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

    IE1.Visible = True
 IE1.navigate "https://some_intranet_url/2" 



    Do While IE1.Busy

         ShowWindow IE1.HWND, 3
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)


    Loop

     Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

 **IE1.document.getElementById("btnAddPerson").Click**



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, I have created a sample using the following code, it works well on my side, you could also check it.

```
Function IEWindowFromTitle(sTitle As String) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim win As Object, rv As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    For Each win In objShellWindows
        If TypeName(win.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            If UCase(win.Document.Title) = UCase(sTitle) Then
                Set rv = win
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set IEWindowFromTitle = rv

End Function
Sub Test1()

'Login into IE

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim IE1 As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim btn As HTMLButtonElement
    Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MyHTML_Element1 As IHTMLElement
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set IE1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.google.com/"

    Do While IE.Busy

         'ShowWindow IE.Hwnd, 3
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set doc = IE.Document

    'Click to Login

    Do While IE.Busy

         'ShowWindow IE.Hwnd, 3
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop


    Do While IE.Busy

        ' ShowWindow IE.HWND, 3
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

    'Set page to be fully loaded
    Loop

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    IE1.Visible = True
    IE1.Navigate "https://www.bing.com/"

    Do While IE1.Busy

         'ShowWindow IE1.Hwnd, 3
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

    Loop

    Do While IE1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    IE1.Document.getElementById("sb_form_q").Value = "vba"
    IE1.Document.getElementById("sb_form_go").Click

End Sub
```

Since, I can't reproduce your problem, I suggest you could refer to the following steps to narrow down the problem, and try to solve it.

```
   IE1.Visible = True
 IE1.navigate "https://some_intranet_url/2" 
    Do While IE1.Busy
         ShowWindow IE1.HWND, 3
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
     Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

 **IE1.document.getElementById("btnAddPerson").Click**
```

First, please check the above code, after navigating to another page, we should wait for the "IE1" instance complete, instead of the "IE" instance. Pleas try to modify the code as below:

```
IE1.Visible = True
IE1.Navigate "https://www.bing.com/"

Do While IE1.Busy

     'ShowWindow IE1.Hwnd, 3
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

Loop

Do While IE1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Second, after navigation success, please check the focus window and use F12 developer tools to check the website resource, make sure you could find the "btnAddPerson" button.

Besides, here is an article about VBA Error 91, you could refer to it:

[Object variable not set (Error 91)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91)